# Сделать искусственную задержку для fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Подскажите как сделать задержку для Fetch через setTimeout?

Есть такой вот метод:

```
const getSearchResult = search => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(`/api/search?query=${search}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else if (response.status === 404) {
          history.push("/search");
        } else {
          throw response;
        }
      })
      .then(json => {
        setSearchResult(json);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Нужно сделать так что бы данные отображались через минимум 1 секунду, но если данные не приходят дольше чем в 1 секунду loading должен продолжаться(Loader крутится), после получения данных убрать loader отобразить данные.

Вообщем так всё и работает. Но данные приходят слишком быстро и loader не успевает нормально отработать для этого и нужна задержка.

Спасибо )

Comment: Вы можете использовать await https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHiUyM_fFME&list=PLqKQF2ojwm3l4oPjsB9chrJmlhZ-zOzWT&index=8

Comment: а в чем проблема? Указать setTimeout и передать в него функцию?

const getData = ()=>setTimeout(getSearchResult, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

Задержку можно вынести в `Promise` и затем дожидаться пока закончатся оба: и запрос и задержка, и только в этом случае убирать лоадер.

для создание Promise с явным временем разрешения можно использовать функцию `delay`

```
function delay(timeout){
    return new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, timeout))
}
```

Для ожидания обоих Promise можно использовать [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
function delay(timeout){
    return new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, timeout))
}

const getSearchResult = search => {
    setLoading(true);
    Promise.all(delay(1000),
      fetch(`/api/search?query=${search}`)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          } else if (response.status === 404) {
            history.push("/search");
          } else {
            throw response;
          }
        })
        .then(json => {
          setSearchResult(json);
        }))
      .then(()=>{
          setLoading(false);
      });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать  добавить промис:

```
    const getSearchResult = (search) => {
    const start = Date.now();
    const getSearchResult = (search) => {
       fetch(`/api/search?query=${search}`).then(response => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                const diff  = Date.now() - start;
                if (diff < 1000) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log('1000');
                        resolve(response);
                    }, 1000-diff);
                } else {
                    resolve(response);
                }
            });
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else if (response.status === 404) {
                history.push('/search');
            } else {
                throw response;
            }
        })
        .then(json => {
            setSearchResult(json);
            setLoading(false);
        });
};
```

В коде  замеряется время выполнения запроса.. и если он меньше  1000 мс то  оставшееся время мы отображаем лодер иначе не отображаем его.